# Advice needed for a final year project on wheelchair automation and control

Tags: signal, control-system, signal-processing, automation, imageprocessing

My project partners and I have been trying to design a wheelchair for people with neuro-degenerative diseases. I know this has been done in the past, however we are using a different approach. We are trying to implement a semi-automatic system, whereby the user can switch to a fully manual or a fully automatic control.

The control signals are provided through an EEG device, so as the name suggests a fully manual system will need the user to control the wheelchair using EEG. The fully automatic portion will implement object detection and distance gauging and ask for the user input to select an object to move towards, and then the wheelchair will automatically move towards that object while avoiding any obstacles.
The method we have decided to use on the part of automation is using a stereo camera configuration for  object detection and using that same setup for measuring the distance, and the algorithm will try to minimize the distance up to a certain threshold. For now we have decided to use triangulation to measure the distance, however we are not sure if that will work with multiple objects in view.

Is the above approach viable? And can it be implemented on a real-time embedded system? Are there any sources I should look up to further aid myself in the project? Any advice will be appreciated.

As a side note, the purpose of using only cameras is to reduce the bulk of the overall machine. And it will provide more flexibility in case we need to update or add certain features. The switch between automatic and manual will also be accomplished through EEG signals.

Comment: wow, that's a huge project! I'd personally recommend you break it down into smaller ones first, and do an estimate of how long each of them will take. To give you an idea of what I'd consider a final year project in size: Selecting an object on a screen using EEG signal processing. For you, it's but a small puzzle piece, but to me it sounds like it could easily fill half a year full time if it needs to be done well enough for it to be used as input to a vehicle steering algorithm. You need to do object recognition, you need to do all the 3D-sensing, and all the EEG processing.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Exactly! Our supervisor said the same thing. However we are knee deep into it already, for now we want to make something a atleast functional, and then we will integrate all the pieces together. We have divided the work in smaller portions, my colleague is working on the EEG side of things, while I have to work on the object detection. So far I have seen a few algorithms I could use however they are not really suitable for real-time applications. What would be viable in this scenario? We are planning to use Jetson Nano for the controller.

Comment: Mubasir, your supervisor tells you that you will not do all this in your time, I tell you you won't do all this in your time. So, pick any subproject, and only do that. You might lose a few weeks of work. Still much better than to work for the whole time, and then have nothing, because you totally underestimated the effort (which you still are doing. stop it. Listen to your supervisor.)!

Comment: @MarcusMüller to be honest sir, I have been thinking about it and leaning to your suggestion as well. Even more so now than before due to the current global conditions, and that's why, for now all I am focusing on is object detection. If we manage to accomplish that in a reasonable amount of time, we can then add another piece to the puzzle. To be perfectly honest I am also not expecting to complete it any time soon, but I am treating this as a learning experience so I have to give it a shot atleast (not the whole project but a part of it). Nevertheless , I am really grateful for the advice :)

Answer (score 0):

To handle stereo imaging, using ONLY a visual camera, I believe the challenge will be the extraction of key image points that are UNAMBIGUOUS in both the left and right cameras. In the 1960s (60 years ago) Hans Morovac used his Points_Of_Interest, formed by a "L" shape of tape; the robot Shakey had two cameras, and had a mainframe computer (in a separate room) to search for the "L" markings. Correlation was then used, and Optic-Flow and Monocular disparity and binocular disparity.

By marking the objects with Black tape, this can be done, except when a 2nd object blocks the view of one of the cameras.

A fast enough camera Frame_Rate, and large "L" markings, would allow continuous tracking of the edges of the several "L"s in your scene, and the 3_D model would result in movement_vectors that predict how the edges of the "L"s will be moving. This prediction of movement is important for reducing the computational requirements.

This --- vector generation and tracking ---- is how I think the human eye is so effective with spotting sudden appearance of threats; ANY SURPRISES, any violation of the expected movement vectors beyond allowed occlusions in the 3_D model, and the human reacts with alarm and with foveation of the eyes.

This is a serious challenge, even for such as the ongoing development of SELF_DRIVING CARS. I've heard the reason the GOOGLE CARS are SO SLOW in turning corners --- is this 3_D problem. Part of the challenge is the constant BOUNCING UP and DOWN of the cameras with roads not being flat.

If you want to explore this, have only 2 or 3 LARGE "L" markings, and track those continuously. Make the markings LARGE, so there is continuous optic flow as the Black Tape Corner is seen to slowly move across the 3_D world model.

Until 5 years ago, simply getting the cameras precisely aligned, so you could perform a useful correlation between L/R images was a BIG DEAL. Only was 5 years ago was this alignment solved.

Our human eyes are continuously tracking, unlike electronic cameras. Thus what seems trivial to us humans, is very difficult for a machine.

Comment: so, rather than detecting objects, it is better to track markers. I believe I get your point, object detection algorithms can be really computationally expensive. Are the L shaped marking necessary? or would any simple shape with well defined edges work, say a box?